# Объясните пожалуйста, как максимально эффективно оптимизировать изображения на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript, html, node.js, gulp

У меня стал актуальным вопрос оптимизации изображений на сайте. 
В данный момент я разработал сайт, на котором используется достаточно большое кол-во изображений (Слайдер в шапке, акции, товары).

Сайт собираю с помощью gulp. Перед сборкой все изображения прогнал через плагины:

```
imagemin
        imageminPngquant
        imageminZopfli
        imageminMozjpeg
        imageminGiflossy
```

Оптимизация дала положительные результаты. Но смущает следующее:

1. У меня используется 1 картинка скажем размера 4000x2000, которая с помощью css сжимается на всех медиа брекпоинтах до нужного размера, а также иногда отображается на автарках товара, которые имеют размер 112 на 60 пикселей.

Меня это натолкнуло на мысль, а почему бы не сделать множество вариантов исходя из оригинального изображения. К примеру:

Оригинал 4000х2000
Для адаптивного дизайна от 768 до 1024 (по бутстрапу) использовать изображение 1024хсоклько то там не важно,
А для аватарок так и сгенерировать 112 пикселей на сколько то там согласно пропорции. Так называемые thumbnails.

Что касается генерации то тут предельно все ясно. Можно сделать таски в галпе где будут генерироваться варианты изображений. Но у меня вопрос о том, как решается задача с подбором картинок, если пользователь зашел с ретина экрана, либо 4-8к? В этом случае необходимо использовать 2х, 3х или 4х изображение.

И как быть с css и html где вставляются урлы на картинку??

Я искал много статей по данной теме, но вокруг одна сплошная вода о том как плохо не оптимизировать изображения, и нигде нет нормальных пособий как организовать то что я описал.

Вот цитата из одной статьи [отсюда](https://serpstat.com/ru/blog/polnij-gajd-po-optimizatcii-kartinok-na-sajte/?lang=ru)

Здесь говорится:

> **Изображения нужно создавать в размере, в котором они будут представлены на сайте.**
>
> Браузеру будет легче сканировать контент страниц, если в CSS прописать
>   ширину и высоту изображения. Для дисплеев с ретиной добавляйте
>   изображения в размере 2x и настройте отображение разных размеров
>   одного и того же изображения для разных экранов. Иначе для
>   пользователей, которые откроют изображение на дисплее с ретиной, все
>   картинки будут отображены с визуальной потерей качества.

А также наводят скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нем особо видно, что в конце урлов изображений стоят 2х и 1.5х.

**Собственно мой вопрос:**

Может кто поделится опытом или исчерпывающей информацией/ссылкой на статью о том как правильно реализовать оптимизацию и использование оптимизированных изображений на сайте?

Comment: Как вариант обратите внимание на LazyLoad https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, делать оптимизация при загрузке.
К примеру загружается фото выше чем 1к на 1к, можно его обрезать до 1000x1000 (тут можно поиграться и обрезать нормально, не квадратом)

Далее, таким образом обрезать под нужные размеры, например 1к,300px,100px и использовать в тех местах,где это нужно

Вот код, который можно переделать под эти нужды:

```
$format = str_replace('image/', '', $file->getMimeType());
$photo_name = md5(rand(10000000, 99999999) . time());
$full_name = $photo_name . '.' . $format;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('PATH_TO_FILE'. $full_name);

if (extension_loaded('imagick') && $width > 500 && $height > 500) {
$imagick = new Imagick(public_path() . '/product/' . $full_name);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$imagick->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(90);
$imagick->thumbnailImage($width / 2, $height / 2, false, false);
$filename_no_ext = $photo_name . '_thumb.jpeg';
file_put_contents('PATH_TO_FILE' . $filename_no_ext, $imagick);
}
```

Тут проверка на размеры больше 500 то происходит сжатие на 2